# Django: dynamically filter many to many field in admin

Tags: django, filter, many-to-many, admin

I have a problem where i have 4 tables called: Company, Category and Items and Campaigns. They are connected as follows:

Category:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name='category name', unique=True)
```

Company:

```
 name = models.CharField(max_length=254, verbose_name='company name')
 telephone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='telephone nr.')
 email = models.CharField(max_length=50, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='email')
 categories = models.ManyToManyField(Category, null=True, blank=True)
```

Item:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=254, verbose_name='name')
company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=False, verbose_name='company')
location = ChainedForeignKey(Location, chained_field='company', chained_model_field='company', verbose_name='category')
```

Campaign:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=254, verbose_name='name')
company = models.ForeignKey(Company, null=False, verbose_name='company')
category = ChainedForeignKey(Category, chained_field='company', chained_model_field='company', verbose_name='category')
items = models.ManyToManyField(Item, null=True, blank=True, verbose_name='items')
start_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='start date and time')
end_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name='end date and time')
```

The problem lies in the Campaign model. In Django admin I want to filter the selectable items by the company and category selected in the same model. How can I dynamically change the item list based upon the selected company and category?

Comment: I think in your case is better if you create a generic relation.. do you know about?!

Comment: I have read about a generic relation but I can't really see how this applies to my situation. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Just one question, you always have company and category entries into campaign right?

Comment: Sorry about the late reaction, but yes I alwasy have a company and category entry in a campaign